# php file upload

Tags: php, file, file-upload

anyone can explain file upload process in PHP. I mean what happens in backend internally.

like saving with temp name, moving to upload folder etc.

I want it's step by step working.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "backend" exactly?

Comment: Good question. I don't quite understand it myself. It seems like a web-server do receive POST data, and then call PHP. PHP core some prepdocessing (decode MIME parts, save file into temporary location)  and then user php code being called.

Comment: yes backend. like temp name, moving to upload folder etc.

Comment: lol it's not a backend :) it's usual upload you are asking for. just follow first Gordon's link and accept his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to **do** file uploads is explained in the [PHP Manual](http://de.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php):

- [POST method uploads](http://de.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)
- [Error Messages Explained](http://de.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)
- [Common Pitfalls](http://de.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php)
- [Uploading multiple files](http://de.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)
- [PUT method support](http://de.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php)

Please go through these chapters to learn how to do uploads.

If you want to know how File Uploads are **implemented** in the PHP core, check out

- http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/rfc1867.c?view=markup

Afaik, this is the module that handles this.

If none of the above do give you the information you are looking for, please refine your question to indicate what is missing.

Comment: May be I am wrong, but there is nothing of PHP internals, e.g. when and how MIME data being decoded, etc