# return back data from php to html

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm newbie of php and html and I've a problem. I have this `form` to upload a file :

```
    <h2>Upload file</h2>                
    <form name="uploadFile" action = "upload.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <input type = "file" name = "document"/>
    <input type = "submit"/>
```

In my external `upload.php` file if the upload is successful I echo a string with the name of the file and a message. If I show the value with the echo function the value is right, but I don't want a redirect to upload.php page, I want to show it back in HTML.

How can I print the return value of my `upload.php` file in HTML form page?

Comment: If you do not want to redirect the user to another page you can handle the POSTdata in the current script.
To check if the form is submitted use an if like this:

`if(isset($_POST['document']))`

Comment: Use ajax and return the response from upload.php to show it on html page

Comment: how can I? can you please provide code or example?

Comment: Whenever you ask anything in the comments. Use @name_of_person .Otherwise he/she will not get notification of comments. Now your problem is solved or you want me to write code ?

Answer (score 2):

Please change your `index.php` file as shown below :

```
<?php
      if(isset($_FILES['document'])) {
        echo $_FILES["document"]["name"];
        echo "<p id='results'></p>";
?>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "data.json",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
               }
           });
        });
</script>

<?php } ?>
<h2>Upload file</h2>                
<form name="uploadFile" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <input type = "file" name = "document"/>
    <input type = "submit"/>
</form>
```

This prints the filename of the file you uploaded.
When you work with file upload, PHP saves **name**, **file size**, and all other attribute to `$_FILES` variable which is a Global Variable.

As you said you want to read other file as soon as file uploaded, this might help.

Comment: yes, It works thanks. I need also to return back another information from the upload.php external script and not only filename. Any idea?

Comment: a string there is content in the document.

Comment: If this answer helps, mark it as an answer, and also upvote it, so that others with the same problem can benefit in future.

Comment: you mean a string that the uploaded file contains?

Comment: yes, I check in the uploaded document same data and than I need to return it back in the html page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144767/discussion-between-nirav-madariya-and-pnappa).

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to the php page with GET variable like this: `upload.php?status=success`
And then you can check for the `status` variable

Comment: Not downvoting but this doesn't help.

Comment: can you please example?

Comment: after finishing uploading you redirect to upload.php right? make a redirect to upload.php?status=success instead. and then you can check the status like this `$status= isset($_GET['status']) ? $_GET['status'] : "noStatus";`

Comment: @RST , i have used it before in collage projects :) and it works when i need to get status after doing a request

Comment: As far as I understand his scenario, his upload.php is where is determined whether or not the upload was successful. You are already sending 'success'. If you can add some code to explain what you are doing, it might help.

Comment: if the request done as expected, the url will be `upload.php?status=success`. and this will be an indication if the request was done successfully or not

Comment: Not Helpful, why adding parameter to URL when you can always use global variables like, $_POST, $_SESSION, etc.

Comment: @RST yes, I need the data back from the upload.php file and not only if it is success or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add your php code for uploading at the top of the file where your form is and name it as .PHP file. Please try the below code,

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['document'])) {
    //do your post actions here
    //validate your input
    //upload the file
    //print success or error message
  }
?>
<h2>Upload file</h2>                
<form name="uploadFile" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
  <input type = "file" name = "document"/>
  <input type = "submit"/>
```

Comment: when your action attribute have `upload.php`, You'll never be back here with `$_POST['document']` not null, It will always redirect to `upload.php` on submit.

Comment: @NiravMadariya, assume that the file itself upload.php or I will have the action empty. I will correct my answer. Sorry, I missed it. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: how in my index.php (where the form is) I show the return data of upload.php form action? In the php if code you posted, how can I print the return data from the upload.php?

Comment: @pnappa, I just corrected my answer based on NiravMadariya's comment. Removed the action attribute to post it to the same page.

Comment: I removed the action attribute, and I add php. The upload works, the page is still the same (without redirect) but the data is not shown. What I have to echo, the $document variable in the php code?

Comment: The global $_FILES will contain all the uploaded file information. Please check, http://us2.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php. Also please refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4013545/4874281

Answer (score -1):

As `Nirav`'s posted an answer. Use it with some modification.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['document'])) {
    echo $_FILES["document"]["name"];
    // when uploaded the file assign status=1;
    $file_name=$_FILES["document"]["name"];
    $status="1";
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var status = <?php echo $status; ?>;
var filename = <?php echo $file_name; ?>;
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(status){
        $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            status:status,
            filename: filename
        }
        success: function(result){
                    $('#element').html(result);
                }
        });
    }
    else{
        $('#element').html("failed"); 
    }

});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Upload file</h2>                
<form name="uploadFile" action="upload.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
  <input type = "file" name = "document"/>
  <input type = "submit"/>
</form>
<div id="element"><!--Here Show message from upload.php--></div>
```

**Upload.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['status']) && !empty($_POST['status'])){

    echo $_POST['filename']." uploaded successfully";
}
?>
```